# Fixed point theorem for multivalued functions on b-metric space

Tags: fixed-point-theorems, multivalued-functions

Hy guys!

I'm studying some fixed point results for multi-valued function on a b-metric space $(X,d,s)$. I'm looking for the proof of a theorem wich is just a generalization of Nadler's results for multi-valued function on a metric space.

Please note that:

**Def.** Let X be a set, and let $s≥1$ be a given real number. A function $d:X×X→R^{+}$ is said to be a $b$-metric if and only if for all $x,y,z\in X$, the following conditions are satisfied:

1. $d(x,y)=0$ if and only if $x=y$.
2. $d(x,y)=d(y,x)$.
3. $d(x,z)≤s[d(x,y)+d(y,z)]$.

A pair $(X,d)$ is called a $b$-metric space.

Here is the theorem I'm looking for.

---

**Theorem**

Let $(X,d)$ be a $b$-complete metric space, and let $T:X→CB(X)$ be a multi-valued mapping such that $T$ satisfies the inequality

$$H(Tx,Ty)≤rd(x,y)$$ for all $x,y\in X$,
where $0<r<\frac{1}{s}$. Then $T$ has a fixed point.

---

Anyone can help me finding the proof of this theorem? I know it is probably by Czerwik [9], as you can see [here](http://www.fixedpointtheoryandapplications.com/content/2013/1/215#B9).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you checked E. Zeidler's _Nonlinear Functional Analysis and its Applications I: Fixed-Point Theorems_? Maybe is this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.03967.pdf) helpfull.

Comment: Are you looking for the particular proof or just any proof?